# Is $1-\cos^2(x)$ a greater infinitesimal than $\sin^3(x)$ as $\to 0+$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, infinitesimals

[image]What I did was to see that both are $\sin$ functions and the first one acts as $x^2$ while the second one goes to $x^3$. So the order of infinitesimal of the first one is $2$ and for the second it is $3$ which means that the second one is an infinitesimal greater than the first one. But our exam portal says the opposite. I just want to make sure I am not confusing the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here comes from unclear notation in the question. The author means $f(x) = 1 - \cos(x^2)$ and not $f(x) = 1-\cos(x)^2$ as you have assumed. You can see this from the author using the notation $\sin^3(x)$ to denote $\sin(x)^3$.

Using this definition of $f$ gives $f(x) \sim \frac{x^4}{2}$ which goes to zero faster than $g(x) = \sin(x)^3$.

Comment: thank you so much
i remember figuring it out last night but i must have forgotten it this morning

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f=1-cos^2x$ you were right, the **infinitesimal order** of $f$ should be 2 and the infinitesimal order of $g$ is 3, then the option given should be wrong.

**EDIT**

As noted, $f=1-cos(x^2)=\frac{x^4}2+o(x^4)$ then the **infinitesimal order** of $f$ is 4.

Comment: is that what is means to be an infinitesimal of order greater than the other because i thought you just compare the exponent of the principal parts

Comment: the infinitesimal order of $sin^3x$ is greater than the infinitesimal order of $sin^2x$  but the infinititesimal part of $ \sin^2x$ is greater

Comment: i have added an image in the question can you please see it ?

Comment: I think that you are correct f has order 2 and g has order 3.

Comment: @M.HamzaAli Sorry I didn't noticed the typo since at first the full text wasn't in the OP and when you added it I didn't verify the text giving for good your assertion. Anyway now it is clear. Bye!

Answer (score 1):

The question is about $1-cos(x^2)$ not $1-cos^2(x).$

Note that  $1-cos(x^2)\sim x^4/2$ which has a greater order of infinitesimal than $sin^3(x)$